# square root of contractions in Baer *-rings

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, baer-rings

Let $A$ be a unital Baer*-ring. We say that $a$ is a contraction if $aa^*\leq1$ and $a^*a\leq1$.

Q1) Assume $a$ is a contraction. Has the positive element $1-aa^*$ any square root?
(if yes, seems $1-aa^*$ has as well.)

Q2) Let $x$ be in $A$. True or false: $x^*x\leq1\to xx^*\leq1$.

Comment: Surely there must be more hypotheses. For example, if $F$ is a subfield of the complexes closed under complex conjugation, then $F$ and all its matrix rings are Baer*. But a positive answer to Q1 for even a single one of these matrix rings forces $F$ to contain square roots of all of its positive elements. So take $F $ to be the rationals, or any algebraic extension thereof (with a complex embedding).

Comment: Instead of *algebraic*, I meant *finite-dimensional*.